# Undervolting with a 2.6.35 kernel?

Tags: 10.10, kernel, intel

I am trying to undervolt my ubuntu 10.10, using the info from the following link:
http://openmindedbrain.info/09/05/2010/undervolting-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lts/

But i can't install the undervolt module because of the kernel in 10.10, do i have to wait for a while before the undervolt module gets updated? or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

For AMD processors there is the excellent [cpupowerd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpupowerd/).
there is a ppa providing it (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:autostatic/ppa` ), but compiling is painless. `make && sudo make install` should do fine.
It needs the msr kernel module loaded (just add it in a new line to `/etc/modules`) 
Play around a little: `sudo cpupowerd -r 0.01` is a good starting point. This reduces the voltage of all cores by .01 Volts for all frequency steps.

It's best to run cpupowerd as a service when you've found the appropriate values. To do so go to `/etc/init.d` copy skeleton to cpupowerd and insert the values that are stable for you. Be sure to always test your settings under high load.

In my case it saved even more power because the tiny undervolting was just enough to keep the fans turned off when I use my laptop for browsing.

**Edit:** For now cpupowerd supports only AMD. The README says that possibly Intel will be supported as well. The status of the project is unclear though.

Answer (score 1):

What hardware are you trying to undervolt? If you're able to dial down the voltage in BIOS that's preferable to doing it in software.

Comment: I have a intel core i5, no i cant change anything in BIOS =( and i also realized i cant undervolt because the processor is locked down by the bios =| the funny thing though is that i suspect windows undervolts my processor! i wonder how

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my guide for the Ubuntu 10.10 and I managed to undervolt without any problems. So far everything seems to work ok.
The updated guide is here: http://openmindedbrain.info/26/10/2010/undervolting-in-ubuntu-10-10-maverick/

Comment: Hey, thanks :D you think it will work with an inter core i5 chip?